# Application won't start on simulators in Xcode 12

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Please tell me, after upgrading to **Xcode 12**, simulators stopped running

There was an error **'in /Users/.../Pods/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(VLCEmbeddedDialogProvider.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file' /Users/.../Pods/MobileVLCKit /MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit 'for architecture arm64'**

I found on the Internet a solution to add **arm64** to **Excluded Architectures** using the Any **iOS Simulator SDK** option, which I did.

Then the same error was only with the **i386** architecture, I added it to the exceptions as well (for project purposes and Pods purposes)

Then the same thing with **x86_64**, added it too

After that the error **'Build input file cannot be found' came out /Users/...Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWSTB-asdgdfgbgfbg.../Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MYNAME.app/MYNAME'**

I tried to clean **DerivedData**, but after that either the error was repeated

I don't know how to solve it

It runs fine on a real device, the problem is only with simulators

Updated **Xcode** to **12.01**, updated cocoapods, updated **mobilevlckit**, error persists

Comment: Any idea to solve this problem?. I have tried all the solution already. but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove `/Library/Developer` (the one from root), or rename it and relaunch your Xcode.

or

- cmd + shift + opt + k

or

- `pod update`

Comment: It did not help :(

Comment: Not solved...The problem is in the framework. Framework does not compile after adding excluded architectures, but if excluded architectures are not added then there will be an architecture error

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the pod **MobileVLCKit**.

The pod devs have added the necessary changes to work well with **Xcode 12.x**

It was necessary to update **MobileVLCKit** to version **3.3.15**

I have not updated above **3.3.13**, then I registered the command `pod install --repo-update`. After that, the repository with the pod was updated and it was possible to install the latest working version

Answer (score 0):

I've an old project migrated to **Xcode 12.4**, **cocoapods**. Same situation. I've solved updating the Build Settings -> **VALID_ARCH** value with (both project and target section) :

```
$(ARCHS_STANDARD) i386
```

**Build architecture only**: **YES**

For your tries remember to removing Derived Data:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already answered my own question)

Comment: You're welcome, for me was needed to remove x86_64, maybe it could be useful for someone else.